# Doing calculations with a mixin without using inline javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mixins

So I'm using a mixin to display a series of entries in my web app. I want each one to have a relative time stamp that says how long ago it was posted.

```
mixin listTitles(titles)
  each title in titles
     article.leaf
      article
    a.headline(href=title.URL)= title.title
  footer
    p.postData 
     | Posted 
     span#date=title.time
     a(href='someSource') The New York Times <br>
    a.commentButton(href=title.URL)
    a.sourceButton(href='#')
mixin listTitles(titles)
```

title.time contains the time of submission in javascript time (unix time in ms). I would like to compare that to the current time and display the time since the post was submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS anywhere inside Jade template by placing `-` in beginning of a line.

```
mixin listTitles(titles)
  - var now = Date.now();
  each title in titles
    p Posted #{now - title.time} millis ago.
```

I assume that by “no javascript” you mean that this logic should be implemented in template itself and not js-file that calls `render()`.

Comment: By no javascript I meant that I wanted the logic to be in script.js and not in the template. Do you know if there are performance drawbacks to doing it the way you suggested? Because I was going to have it convert the time to minutes, hours and days and concatenate it.

Comment: @user1816679 Of course you can: calculate it and pass to `render` function in same way you passing `titles`. (See [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) and [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) in Express.) Jade compiles to JS function, so I don't think there will be major improvement. Do you need it anyway? IMHO it's about code's structure. Caching templates, using `self: false` and `compileDebug: false` for Jade options is far better perfomance investment (see Google on those).

Comment: moment.js has some handy time ago methods http://momentjs.com/ eg. `moment("20130218", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();`